# How much memory is required to represent an address?

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the following piece of code.

```
int var;

cout << (long)&var;
```

My doubt is how do we know that long int has sufficient width to hold the memory location indicated by `&var`. What if it is not sufficient?

The full code which I am executing...

```
//: C03:YourPets2.cpp
// From Thinking in C++, 2nd Edition
// Available at http://www.BruceEckel.com
// (c) Bruce Eckel 2000
// Copyright notice in Copyright.txt
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int dog, cat, bird, fish;

void f(int pet) {
  cout << "pet id number: " << pet << endl;
}

int main() {
  int i, j, k;
  cout << "Address size " << sizeof(&f) << endl;
  cout << "Long size " << sizeof(long) << endl;
  cout << "Intptr size " << sizeof(intptr_t) << endl;
  cout << "f(): " << &f << endl;  
  cout << "f(): " << (long)&f << endl;
  cout << "f(): " << (long long)&f << endl;
  cout << "dog: " << (long)&dog << endl;
  cout << "cat: " << &cat << endl;
  cout << "bird: " << &bird << endl;
  cout << "fish: " << (long)&fish << endl;
  cout << "i: " << (long)&i << endl;
  cout << "i: " << (long long)&i << endl;
  cout << "j: " << (long)&j << endl;
  cout << "k: " << (long)&k << endl;
} ///:~
```

The result which I am getting:

```
Address size 4
Long size 4
Intptr size 4
f(): 1
f(): 134514548
f(): 134514548
dog: 134521044
cat: 0x804a0d8
bird: 0x804a0dc
fish: 134521056
i: -1074729380
i: -1074729380
j: -1074729384
k: -1074729388
```

Comment: In C++11 you can use `std::intptr_t` from `<cstdint>`, which is guaranteed to be able to hold any pointer value. It was first introduced in C99.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. It's possible - if unlikely - for pointers to have larger storage requirements than any integer. If there is an integer type that is suitable then there will be a typedef for it `std::intptr_t` (and possible also `std::uintptr_t`) defined in `<cstdint>` (C++11 only).

You can test for the presence of `intptr_t` at the preprocessor stage by testing for the definedness of the macro `INTPTR_MAX` (or `INTPTR_MIN`) after `#include <cstdint>`.

If you just want to print a pointer value using `std::cout` then you can cast to `void*` (unnecessary for `int*` but necessary for `char*`) and use `<<` directly without a cast to an integer type.

Comment: got more curious. Why typecast to void is necessary for char and not for int ?

Comment: @bubble: because using `cout << ptr` when `ptr` is of type `char*` will treat it as a null-terminated string instead of displaying the pointed-to address.

Comment: and why do we have intptr_t and uintptr_t. I mean signed and unsigned ? Is it correct to have negative memory addresses ?

Comment: @bubble, there are a few scenarios where pointer arithmetic on these converted typed is allowed and you could use negatives. However, I suspect it is more just for compatibilitiy with external APIs which take only a signed integer, or only an unsigned one.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y i am getting negative values for a programm as simple as the one which is written above in the question.

Comment: @bubble: Pointers aren't integers and they don't have a sign. When converted to an signed integer some pointer values might convert to a value that has a negative value but this doesn't (necessarily) mean the the system uses "negative" addresses.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Why are they getting converted to negative values ?

Comment: @CharlesBailey Posting more code and result which I am getting. Please have a look

Comment: @bubble: I don't see any additional question. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @CharlesBailey I meant why does the address value is getting converted to negative. Even when I am typecasting it as long long which I suppose will provide it sufficient space to get it represented in its positive form.

Comment: @bubble: Why do you care? The implementation can map addresses into integers in any way it sees fit. The only thing you can do with the result of converting a pointer to an integer which has any meaning is to convert it back to a pointer of the original type so you can dereference it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an assert (or a different kind of check).
The check should be in the form

> assert( sizeof( &var ) <= sizeof(long) );

Comment: You mean there is no way to say anything beforehand ?

Comment: I mean just by knowing the configuration of the machine viz. RAM size, word size etc..

Comment: This assert will fail with MSVC++ on x86-64. So it's not much of a solution.

Comment: @interjay, that's exactly the  point, the long is not large enough to hold a pointer, thus the assertion fails.

Comment: Consider using c++11's `static_assert` or the one from boost so you can get a compile time exception rather than runtime.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: My point was that it isn't very helpful to have code that just tells you something won't work. What is needed is a method of getting it to work.

Comment: @interjay, on the contrary, when doing cross-platform work, or where you have several compilation options, or just using many libraries, static_assert's are great ways to immediately identify compatibility problems.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Static asserts are obviously better than making blind assumptions about the platform, but there's no need to resort to them when you can write portable code, as you can in this case. This answer doesn't help someone who wants to convert a pointer to an integer in a portable manner - it just gives code that will fail to compile on some platforms.